# Limit of sequence that is root of sums of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Suppose $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ are complex numbers with $|z_1|>\cdots>|z_k|$, and let $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ be non-zero complex numbers. Let $a_0,a_1,\ldots$ be the sequence defined by

$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iz_i^n$$

Is it true that $|a_n|^{1/n}$ has a limit as $n \to \infty$ given by $|z_1|$?

**Progress**: I don't want to mislead anyone into thinking that this is the best way to approach the problem, but I can show that $|a_n| \leq (|c_1|+\cdots+|c_k|)|z_1|^n$ and so $\lim\sup |b_n|^{1/n} \leq |z_1|$.

Intuition-wise, it seems plausible that the limit is being controlled by the number with the largest absolute value.

Comment: If and only if $c_1\ne0$.

Comment: oh right silly me. I shall edit the non-zero conditions. But why is the largest non-zero "contributing factor" giving the limit? (which is essentially my question)

Comment: @suncup224 : When you write \Sigma instead of \sum, then in a "displayed" setting you see $\displaystyle\Sigma_{i=1}^n$ instead of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n$.  In an "inline" context there is still a difference but it's subtler.  I also did some other copy-editing of your question, including writing $\lim\sup$ instead of $lim sup$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
|a_n|^{1/n}=|z_1|\cdot|c_1|^{1/n}\cdot\left|1+\sum_{i=2}^k\frac{c_i}{c_1}\left(\frac{z_i}{z_1}\right)^n\right|^{1/n}$$
Each factor on the RHS should have an obvious limit. If it isn't so, just yell.

This uses only the hypotheses that $|z_1|\gt|z_i|$ for every $i\ne1$ and that $c_1\ne0$.